# How to store Android Table Data in MySQL efficiently

Tags: android, mysql, json, android-gridview, android-tablelayout

I want to store Android Table Data from my App into a MySQL database. Users can create tables and insert data and save those tables. For me it seems quite inefficient to save the table as corresponding rows and columns in the Database, because many tables mean many MySQL entries.

Is there any method more efficiently to achieve that? I'm thinking of using the MySQL json format to store the row and column data of an Android table so it will represent only one row in MySQL.

I have to store a table id and additional information for each table. These informations would be redundant if I choose the method of simply adding row and column data directly to MySQL.

Any hints on how to do this?

Comment: Does your app need to be able to search or sort by the fields created by your users?

Comment: Not yet. It is just an App for note taking and I want to support tables

Comment: "Not Yet" can be a trap. If you will ever need to search or sort by those fields, your design would be different for the tables than if you don't need to access the fields via MySQL's WHERE or ORDER BY (or any other clauses). If you will need to do such things in the future, and you don't design for them now, you will probably end up with a major re-write of the DB side of things

Comment: The problem with the classic table approach is, that the user can choose on client side, how many entries a table contains. Therefore I can't use predefined tables and I need a new database table for each user table Layout.

Comment: An alternative is to define some "standard" columns that could be sorted/searched. Then define the table with these columns, and add a JSON column for the user defined columns. For example: ```date_created, date_modified, user_id, subject, category, user_fields```. Then document which columns can be searched/sorted. There are functions in mysql that allow you access to individual columns in the JSON, but they will greatly affect performance.